# Java generic type keyboard input

Tags: java, generics, java.util.scanner

I have a class that has an `edit()` method that takes `fieldName` and `newValue` as parameters and edits the field accordingly. Of course, this `fieldName` must be generic type `<T>` in order to satisfy the different types of variables in that class. The user will have to input from the keyboard.

By using `Scanner` for the user input, is there a way to ask for a generic value from the keyboard?

Comment: no, `Scanner` can parse primitive types and strings only. So you should create objects of required type of your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound like generics are what you want here.

Generics are used when you want to support any given type, and you can be *reasonably* intelligent about what you're doing with that homogeneity.

When it comes to user input, you're restricted to the primitive types and `String` - so you already have a very narrow domain before you, and adding generics to that would only confuse and complicate the matter.

Since you don't really explain how you're planning on tying `fieldName` to `edit` (and I don't think you mean reflection), I'd recommend that you rely on `newValue` and the type that it needs to bind to and read that from the `Scanner` instead.